# How to make this query faster: TOP N over TOP 1 in past + all in future

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table that contains some data. There are some attributes that are used to 'group' the rows and there is a date column.
I'm trying to improve the performance of a query that basically gets TOP X rows from this table, where it returns *only* the latest row if the data is in the past + all future rows.

My data:

| Id | GroupingId | Date | Whatever |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Value1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-02 | Value2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-01-03 | Value3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2040-01-01 | Value1 |

My query:

```sql
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY GroupingId
                ORDER BY Date DESC) 
            as rnk
        FROM myData
        WHERE Date <= SYSUTCDATETIME()
        UNION
        SELECT *, 1 as rnk
        FROM myData
        WHERE Date > SYSUTCDATETIME()
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rnk = 1
    ORDER BY GroupingId
    OFFSET 0 ROWS Fetch NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

My expected output:

| Id | GroupingId | Date | Whatever |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-02 | Value2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2040-01-01 | Value1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-01-03 | Value3 |

Note that the above is huge simplification of the actual data structure. But This seems to be the culprit. Basically, due to the order by (and possibly filtering conditions that might show up), sql server needs to 'materialize' (aka read from disk) the whole first part of the cte. I'm looking for a way to modify the query/index strategy/indexed view so that the query can be executed without loading everything into memory and just reading top X rows from index/whatever. In essence, this query needs to execute instantly, even if the table has many milions of rows.

EDIT 1:

Execution plan for the above [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy2NzszCo)

Index that is already there:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_groupingId_date_test] ON [dbo].[myData]
(
    [GroupingId] ASC,
    [Date] DESC
)
```

Some other useful info:

Yes, the data is distributed so that there is much more data to be expected in the past. E.g. for every `GroupingId` there might be couple of rows in the future but dozens/hundreds in the past.

Removing the union makes the query super fast. This is actually the recent change that caused the performance problem that I'm trying to fix.

Comment: `UNION` causes another SORT and deletes duplicates, I believe that you can try `UNION ALL` instead and see if it changes the execution plan

Comment: @LuisLL Tried that already (should have mention in the question, sry). Yes, the plan is different, but it doesn't change anything for performance. In both cases, it still uses `merge join` for the union.

Comment: What does the execution plan show? What indexes do you have? Please share [some additional info](https://erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: Perhaps this is being master of the obvious, but is the date column indexed?

Comment: @RobertSievers Well, there's one on GroupingId. Even with a separate index on date, it only makes the 2nd part of the union faster (not a lot of rows in the future), but it still loads pretty much whole table for the 1st part of it.

Comment: You need index on GroupingID, Date

Comment: @Stu, I believe that the index should be on Date first, because the WHERE date, and then comes the GROUP BY

Comment: The problem is the row_number is sorting by GroupId first and then sorting again for Date. Ideally you need to limit the rows before applying the row number and even more ideally perhaps a separate index on Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, some comments got me thinking and on a right track. I figured, I basically need a way to get rid of the Union/merge join from the query plan and have nested loops, so the query can be executed sequentially all the way.

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM mydata o
    WHERE (o.date > SYSUTCDATETIME() OR (
        o.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM mydata s WHERE s.groupingid = o.groupingid AND s.date < SYSUTCDATETIME() ORDER BY DATE DESC)))
) r
ORDER BY r.groupingid
```

This gets me from 1 minute in the original query (or the other answers so far) to below 100ms.
New query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1sQdhM0s

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the `MERGE JOIN` is a result of the `UNION ALL`.
usually when `MERGE JOIN` is the most expensive part is due to the fact that one on of the sides has a big residual. And in this case, you are having up to 100  more rows in the upper SELECT that in the lower one.

I would try something like

```
CREATE TABLE myData (
    Id int,
    GroupingId  INT,
    [Date] DATE,
    Whatever varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO myData(Id,GroupingId, Date,Whatever)
          SELECT 1 Id, 1    GroupingId, '2023-01-01' Date, 'Value1' Whatever
union all select 2,    1              , '2023-01-02'     , 'Value2'
union all select 3,    2              , '2023-01-03'     , 'Value3'
union all select 4,    1              , '2040-01-01'     ,' Value1'


WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY GroupingId
            ORDER BY Date DESC) 
        as rnk
    FROM myData
    WHERE Date <= SYSUTCDATETIME()
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 1 as rnk
FROM myData
WHERE Date > SYSUTCDATETIME()
ORDER BY GroupingId
OFFSET 0 ROWS Fetch NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

This should remove the `MERGE JOIN` and leave you with `CONCATENATION`

[Edit 1]
Thank you for posting the query plan.
try creating the suggested index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_date_test] ON [dbo].[myData]
(
    [Date] DESC
)
INCLUDE (
    groupingId, 
    id
)
```

Comment: Execution plan for this: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ5M4sMRj
There's still a 'MERGE JOIN (CONCATENATION)` operator in it and it still reads pretty much whole table.

Comment: @macwier, did you notice that the `SORT` operator at top is spilling to TempDB and is the operator that takes most the time? Are the statistics on the table up-to-date? Also note that you are scanning the full table both times, (`clustered index scan`), to pick very rows each time. did you try creating the suggested index? Lastly note that the `MERGE JOIN (CONCATENATION)` is only for 100 rows, how many rows participated in the original `MERGE JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approacg, instead of making a row_number over the whole table firs gather the "last" of evry groupingid, the get only 1 row per grouping incase there are multiple entries, as you only have n groupingid  and some baggage you should get fatser to your result.

for this query only ([GroupingId],[Date])  need a comnied index,which must be expended with your actual data.

```
CREATE TABLE myData
    ([Id] int, [GroupingId] int, [Date] Datetime, [Whatever] varchar(6)
  , Primary key(Id), INDEX IX_MyTable4 NONCLUSTERED ([GroupingId],[Date]) )
;
    
INSERT INTO myData
    ([Id], [GroupingId], [Date], [Whatever])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2023-01-01', 'Value1'),
    (2, 1, '2023-01-02', 'Value2'),
    (3, 2, '2023-01-03', 'Value3'),
    (4, 1, '2040-01-01', 'Value1')
;
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT m1.* FROM myData m1 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX([Date]) max_date, [GroupingId] FROM myData WHERE [Date]  <= SYSUTCDATETIME() GROUP BY [GroupingId]) m2
  ON m1.[GroupingId] = m2.[GroupingId] AND m1.[Date] = m2.max_date WHERE m1.[Date]  <= SYSUTCDATETIME()),
CTE2 as (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY GroupingId
                ORDER BY Date DESC) 
            as rnk
        FROM CTE)
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE rnk = 1
UNION ALL
        SELECT *,1
        FROM myData
        WHERE Date > SYSUTCDATETIME()

ORDER BY GroupingId
OFFSET 0 ROWS Fetch NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

| Id | GroupingId | Date | Whatever | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-02 00:00:00.000 | Value2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2040-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Value1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-01-03 00:00:00.000 | Value3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xfPCd_jq)